# GDAL ogr2ogr OracleSpatial to Shape: Multipolygons with wholes/multiparts are missing

Tags: shapefile, gdal, polygon, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial

We're holding geodata in an Orcale database (11g) with spatial extension. I want to unload specific polygons and convert them into Shape for further local processing.

The table where I'm unloading from holds polygons/multipolygons: Oracle Spatial GeomTypes are 4003 and 4007 (4D-Polygon and 4D-Multipolygon - third and fourth axis are not used however).

For unloading and conversion I use this command within a python-script:

```
ogr2ogr.main(["", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", result_path + query_result, connection_params,"-nlt", "MULTIPOLYGON", "-sql", the_sql_query_here])
```

Connection and convertion only seems to work for polygons with GeomType 4003 however:

[image]

Multipartpolygons or polygons with wholes (GeomType 4007) are completely ignored (white gaps). I already tried to rerun the command above with `POLYGON` or `PROMOTE_TO_MULTI` instead of `MULTIPOLYGON`. No change in the result though.

Any known caveats or workarounds regarding this problem?

My GDAL is v2.1.2

---

As requested in the comments I publish the geom-content of an object whose geometry couldn't be loaded:

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(4007,NULL,NULL,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1005,5,1,2,1,5,2,1,9,2,1,13,2,1,17,2,1,25,1005,5,25,2,1,29,2,1,33,2,1,37,2,1,41,2,1),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(33433109.145,5711835.706,9999.9999,0,33433166.721,5711687.09,9999.9999,0,33433229.435,5711904.544,9999.9999,0,33433205.628,5711904.647,9999.9999,0,33433175.618,5711821.022,9999.9999,0,33433109.145,5711835.706,9999.9999,0,33433020.391,5711673.812,9999.9999,0,33433153.215,5711635.136,9999.9999,0,33433164.011,5711674.531,9999.9999,0,33433099.673,5711838.076,9999.9999,0,33433071.502,5711844.871,9999.9999,0,33433020.391,5711673.812,9999.9999,0))
```

Corresponding real life object is multipart and looks like this:

[image]

---

While the geometry doesn't get converted, the objects non-spatial attributes and values get fully converted to shape .

Comment: Could you try to cast the polygons into 3D or 2D with the SQL parameter?

Comment: Thx, but I did not find any oracle-sql to cast 'on-the-fly' within a select statement. Also, regarding to role-management I am not able to create views, functions or modify table data directly. I tried the QGIS-loader (3.2.0) now, which seems to have a problem with the missing SRIDof the Oracle-geom-colums. It does not accept a NULL-value.

Comment: Oh, it probably is very complicated with oracle, see for example this https://spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/348/convert-single-geometry-to-multi-part-geometry-in-oracle-spatial. Could you add one such SDO_GEOMETRY as text into your question?

Comment: Added as Edit 1

Comment: For the sake of completeness: With Oracles { sdo_cs.make_2d() } -function flatening of 3D geometries into 2D works on the fly. For 4D it has to be used twice. Sadly ogr/GDAL couldn't deal with that either.

Comment: You mean holes?

Answer (score 1):

I can only confirm the issue by running this ogrinfo command:

```
ogrinfo OCI:user/password@database -sql "select MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(4007,NULL,NULL,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1005,5,1,2,1,5,2,1,9,2,1,13,2,1,17,2,1,25,1005,5,25,2,1,29,2,1,33,2,1,37,2,1,41,2,1),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(33433109.145,5711835.706,9999.9999,0,33433166.721,5711687.09,9999.9999,0,33433229.435,5711904.544,9999.9999,0,33433205.628,5711904.647,9999.9999,0,33433175.618,5711821.022,9999.9999,0,33433109.145,5711835.706,9999.9999,0,33433020.391,5711673.812,9999.9999,0,33433153.215,5711635.136,9999.9999,0,33433164.011,5711674.531,9999.9999,0,33433099.673,5711838.076,9999.9999,0,33433071.502,5711844.871,9999.9999,0,33433020.391,5711673.812,9999.9999,0)) as geom from dual"
```

The result is `MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY`.

Perhaps you would like to send a question to gdal-dev mailing list about this issue.

Comment: Thanks you for your effort! The corresponding GDAL-DEV-thread can be found here: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2018-August/048958.html